# PHP ImageMagick script not working when executed via command line

Tags: php, command-line, imagemagick

I have a PHP script I'm trying to execute via the command line using the exec() function and I'm getting errors saying PHP can't locate the various classes that are part of the PHP ImageMagick extension (PECL is what I'm using) but it is installed correctly and works fine when running other scripts that use it via the browser.

I'm executing my code this way to create multiple instances and essentially cause parallel processing by allowing Linux to optimize the various processes across my CPU cores on its own. It works great for all the other things I use it for, but not in this situation.

Do I need to change how I installed Imagemagick?

Comment: Post your code! Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

PECL Extension was missing from CLI INI File. Apparently there are two of those files, on for browser execution and another for command line interface.

Comment: Are you planning to tell us where the two different files are located, what their names are, which is which and how you added the extension?